# Use struct as a global for libraries

Tags: c++, struct, libraries

I'm making my own library, and I have a issue. When I pre-declarate a function in .h file, does not recognize it, as it logical. And I don't know how to do.

In Vector2Lib.cpp I have a struct:

```
struct Vector2{
   float x; 
   float y; 
};
```

And a function, it equals a vector:

```
    Vector2 sumaVector(Vector2 x, Vector2 y) {
       Vector2 vectorSumado; 

       vectorSumado.x = x.x + y.x;
       vectorSumado.y = x.y + y.y;

       return vectorSumado;
    }
```

When I predeclarate in .h file:

```
Vector2 sumaVector(Vector2 x, Vector2 y);
```

It doesn't recognize the Vector2 struct. How can I do?

Sorry for my bad english, I apologise in advance. Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "It doesn't recognize the Vector2 struct" ? What is "it", what is "recognize" ? If you have any error message please post it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the definition of the `struct` also in the .h file.

The .h file should look like:

```
#pragma once

// Define the struct.
struct Vector2{
   float x; 
   float y; 
};

// Declare the function.
Vector2 sumaVector(Vector2 x, Vector2 y);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can solve your problem with two ways either you can write

```
typedef struct {
                float x; 
                float y; }Vector2;

int main(){

    Vector2 tmpVec;
    tmpVec.x=10.0;
    tmpVec.y=30.0;
    //// 
 }
```

or you can do write a code sample like this

```
struct Vector2{
     float x;     
     float x;   
};
int main(){

    stuct Vector2 tmpVec;
    tmpVec.x=10.0;
    tmpVec.y=30.0;
    //// 
 }
```

Comment: It's C++, not C. Neither `typedef` nor `struct` in `struct Vector2 tmpVec;` aren't needed.